# any easy way to get imagenet dataset for training custom model in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my experiment, I want to train my custom model on `imagenet` datasets. For simplicity, I am interested 10/100 class classification task. But, direct downloading `imagenet` dataset from `tfds` requires a lot of space on a hard disk. Is there any workaround we could subset `imagenet` dataset so the subsetted `imagenet` dataset could fit for 10/100 class classification task? Does anyone know any way of making this happen? any idea?

In general, `cifar10`, `cifar100` is quite handy to work with functional api of TensorFlow. But, in my experiment, I want to train my own model on `imagenet`. I want to avoid download `imagenet` dataset directly, instead, I want something less computational approach so I can train my custom model on subsetted `imagenet` (10 or 100 class classification). is there any way around to do this? any thoughts?

**my attempt to download `imagenet`**

this is my attempt to download `imagenet` dataset locally, then train my custom model on `imagenet` dataset. But it is time-consuming to download and load data for training. But this is what I did:

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

## fetch imagenet dataset directly
imagenet = tfds.image.Imagenet2012()

## describe the dataset with DatasetInfo
C = imagenet.info.features['label'].num_classes
n_train = imagenet.info.splits['train'].num_examples
n_validation = imagenet.info.splits['validation'].num_examples

assert C == 1000
assert n_train == 1281167
assert n_validation == 50000

imagenet.download_and_prepare()   ## need more space in harddrive

# load imagenet data from disk as tf.data.Datasets
datasets = imagenet.as_dataset()
train_data, validation_data= datasets['train'], datasets['validation']
assert isinstance(train_data, tf.data.Dataset)
assert isinstance(validation_data, tf.data.Dataset)
```

If I do like this, this is time-consuming to download and needs more space on a hard-drive. Is there any easier way to subset `imagenet` dataset and get it from TensorFlow? Does anyone know an easier way of getting a smaller `imagenet` dataset for 10/100 classification task? any thoughts?

**desired output**

usually we can get `cifar10`, `cifar100` from `tf.keras.datasets`. Can we subset the imagenet dataset to something range to (200k ~ 500K)? Is there any less painful approach to get imagenet dataset for training a custom model on `imagenet` data? any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. I need to use `tiny_imagenet_200`:

```
import os, sys, wget
from zipfile import ZipFile

url = 'http://cs231n.stanford.edu/tiny-imagenet-200.zip'
tiny_imgdataset = wget.download('http://cs231n.stanford.edu/tiny-imagenet-200.zip', out = os.getcwd())
for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file.endswith(".zip"):
        zip = ZipFile(file)
        zip.extractall()
    else:
        print("not found")
```